# Authorize and AllowAnonymous asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Please explain what I'm doing wrong. I need the entire controller to be available only for a specific authorized role, but one method from the controller was open to everyone. But when using `[AllowAnonymous]`, I have everything open to everyone. How do I do this correctly?

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public class FilesDBController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public FileResult DownloadFile(int id)
        {                
        }
    }
```

Comment: In such case you have to apply Authorize attribute to all action except above one. If you put Authorize attribute at controller level then it fails at first place without checking action. Other option is to create another controller and move this action there so your current code will work

Comment: Thank you, my mistake, I looked again at the Logout method and realized that it only responds to HttpPost. Everything was normal here.